Do RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f/d fetch bot path / URL?
I want to send bots to a specific file on my website. My question is what do RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f and RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d do? Do they visit the pages (to get the URLs) where the bots visited or do they just get the name of the bots.php file? I'm a bit confused.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ClaudeBot [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Bytespider

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /bots.php [L]

</IfModule>

Thank you in advance.

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond: "REQUEST_FILENAME: The full local filesystem path to the file or script matching the request, if this has already been determined by the server at the time REQUEST_FILENAME is referenced. Otherwise, such as when used in virtual host context, the same value as REQUEST_URI."

And the -f and -d flags, test if the supplied value matches an existing file or folder; the preceding ! negates these tests.

@CBroe so basically it fetches the path of the bots.php file, correct?

This is an internal rewrite - so the server will return whatever content /bots.php generates. The URL the client sees does not change (for that, you'd need to make an external redirect.)
